# Dinamically populating the select options but changing the textContent values (not Jquery please)

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have this `select`and I'm dinamically populating its `options` from a `localStorage` string. But I'm running into an issue; when selecting more than once the options are repeated increasing each time.

The second thing is that I would need to change the textContent from a list and not to show the option values.

This is my `javascript`;

```
    function populatepymnt(key){
    var select = document.getElementById("pymntselect");

    var i=select.options.length-1;i>=1;i--;

    var all = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));

    var payments = all[0].payments;

    var taxes = [];

    for (var i in payments[0]){
        if ((i != "total") && (i != "di") && (i !="myp") && (!i.includes("br")) && (i!="lapse") && (i != "id") && (i != "ldate"))
        {
            taxes.push(i);
        }
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < taxes.length; i++){
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = taxes[i];
    el.value = taxes[i];
    select.appendChild(el);
    }
}
```

This is the `localStorage` string;

```
    [{"payments":
    [{"id":"1",
    "ldate":"10/01/2022 12:00 am",
    "lapse":"Unde at voluptate ma",
    "di":"71",
    "myp":"27",
    "pirtcp":"100",
    "pirtcpbr":"Adipisci quia magna ",
    "pcvs":"3756",
    "pcvsbr":"Voluptatum voluptate",
    "rent":"65",
    "rentbr":"Reprehenderit aliqu"},{"id":"2",
    "ldate":"02/01/2022 12:00 am",
    "lapse":"Mollit qui blanditii",
    "di":"10",
    "myp":"30",
    "pirtcp":"92",
    "pirtcpbr":"Explicabo Optio et",
    "pcvs":"63546",
    "pcvsbr":"Tempora ut perferend",
    "rent":"30",
    "rentbr":"Impedit molestiae e"
    }]
}]
```

And this is my `html`;

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <script>
    var data = [{"payments":[{"id":"1","ldate":"10/01/2022 12:00 am","lapse":"Unde at voluptate ma","di":"71","myp":"27","pirtcp":"100","pirtcpbr":"Adipisci quia magna ","pcvs":"3756","pcvsbr":"Voluptatum voluptate","rent":"65","rentbr":"Reprehenderit aliqu"},{"id":"2","ldate":"02/01/2022 12:00 am","lapse":"Mollit qui blanditii","di":"10","myp":"30","pirtcp":"92","pirtcpbr":"Explicabo Optio et","pcvs":"63546","pcvsbr":"Tempora ut perferend","rent":"30","rentbr":"Impedit molestiae e",}]}]
    localStorage.setItem("f7Clients", JSON.stringify(data));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table align="center" style="width: 430px;">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Services:</td>
            <td>
                <select id="pymntselect" onclick="populatepymnt('f7Clients')" style="width: 200px;">
                    <option value="All">All</option>
                </select>
            </td>

            <td align="right">Services:</td>
            <td>
                <select style="width: 200px;">
                    <option selected value="All">All</option>
                    <option value="pirtcp">Car tax</option>
                    <option value="pcvs">House tax</option>
                    <option value="rent">Other taxes</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the list of `textContent` equivalents I would like to use;

```
pirtcp = Car tax
pcvs = House tax
rent = Other tax
```

As you can see there are two selects. The second one is just to show how I would need to arrange the first select. Any idea on how to fix the issue and populate the options using the equivalents from the list?

Comment: if you for example select `House tax` from the second dropdown do you want only `pcvs` to be shown in the first dropdown?

Comment: No, the second dropdown is just to show how I want the first to show using the string and a list with the values I want to show. What I need is to dinamically populate the first select just as it is right now but showing the textContent from an arragment. Something like this "where the option value is pcvs show Tax house, and where the option value is rent show Other tax, and so on..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you first make an object with all taxes that will be populated in the select dropdown:

```js
const taxes = {
  pirtcp: 'Car tax',
  pcvs: 'House tax',
  rent: 'Other taxes',
}
```

Then update `populatepymnt()` so it clears all the options except that default `All`, get keys from `localStorage` and populate the dropdown.

```js
function populatepymnt(key) {
  select.innerHTML = '<option value="All">All</option>'
  const all = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key))
  const payments = all[0].payments

  /* 
    Instead of looping through all of 'payments[0]' keys, loop through 
    the keys in 'taxes' and check if they exist in 'payments[0]'
  */
  for (const key in taxes) {
    if (payments[0][key]) {
      const el = document.createElement('option')
      el.value = key
      el.textContent = taxes[key]
      select.appendChild(el)
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a working example. Note that the snippets don't allow accessing `localStorage` that is why I am using the `data` object directly.

```js
const taxes = {
  pirtcp: 'Car tax',
  pcvs: 'House tax',
  rent: 'Other taxes',
}

const data = [{"payments":[{"id":"1","ldate":"10/01/2022 12:00 am","lapse":"Unde at voluptate ma","di":"71","myp":"27","pirtcp":"100","pirtcpbr":"Adipisci quia magna ","pcvs":"3756","pcvsbr":"Voluptatum voluptate","rent":"65","rentbr":"Reprehenderit aliqu"},{"id":"2","ldate":"02/01/2022 12:00 am","lapse":"Mollit qui blanditii","di":"10","myp":"30","pirtcp":"92","pirtcpbr":"Explicabo Optio et","pcvs":"63546","pcvsbr":"Tempora ut perferend","rent":"30","rentbr":"Impedit molestiae e",}]}]

const select = document.getElementById('pymntselect')

function populatepymnt() {
  select.innerHTML = '<option value="All">All</option>'
  const payments = data[0].payments
  for (const key in taxes) {
    if (payments[0][key]) {
      const el = document.createElement('option')
      el.value = key
      el.textContent = taxes[key]
      select.appendChild(el)
    }
  }

  /* Just for debugging */
  select.addEventListener('change', () => {
    console.clear()
    console.log('Value = ', select.value)
  })
  /* ------------------ */
}

populatepymnt()
```

```html
<select id="pymntselect" style="width: 200px">
  <option value="All">All</option>
</select>
```